# Call to undefined function wp_delete_user()

Tags: wordpress

Hello I am new to Wordpress and PHP and I am trying to delete an user in a function in a plugin.

```
wp_delete_user( $user->ID );
```

Everything is working well but when I try to use **wp_delete_user** i get the following error:

```
Call to undefined function wp_delete_user() in /homepages/6/d480314532/htdocs/wsb7416187601/zisteau_web/wp-content/plugins/patreon-wordpress-master/classes/patreon_wordpress.php on line 135
```

This function is located in wp-includes/user.php. Are there any way to import this funtionality to use it there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## At first, please ask WP questions at:
[Wordpress.Stackexchange.com](http://Wordpress.Stackexchange.com)

**p.s.:** before that line insert:

```
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php');
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this in a Google search and wanted to add this for anyone looking for a solution when using WordPress multisite. Instead of loading wp-admin/includes/user.php, you'll need to load wp-admin/includes/ms.php like:

`require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/ms.php' );`

Comment: is it possible to include this file inside the plugin`s code?